# TypeScript: Namespace vs Class

Tags: typescript, module, namespaces, class-design

Well it was harder then I thought but I figured out how to encapsulate my code using a `namespace`

I already know how to do it with a `class` (I’m coming from C# world)

And for the question, I had a small `class` that just needed an initiation and then it start working (without exporting any function or property) to do its infinite internal job.

I was told that in my case it’s not a good practice to use a `class`, because I’ll always have only one instance that not exporting anything so I need to use `internal module` instead...

Now all my code is working great inside of a `namespace`, is it a good practice to encapsulate it in a `class` too?

```
namespace X { class Y { } }
```

Or should I leave it without a class?

My module code is bunch of functions that works together using a shared internal state.

A great answer will explain with details the reasons when to use a `namespace`, when to use a `class`, when to use **both**, and when to use **nothing**.

Until now I didn’t find a page that explain the best practice for each, and I believe that a great answer to my question will receive a lot of great feedback (or upvotes ;) ) from confused new comers like me.

Comment: Are you not already using ES6 modules? That would be the ideal IMO.

Comment: @Aaron I guess I do, can you explain with a small piece of code?

Comment: Well its just using `export` and `import` syntax in a file. This makes the file an isolated module. At that point using a namespace or class for isolation is not needed, although using a class to create instances and store state is obviously still useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Typescript.

First. Since we in javascript land import code using

```
import { some_exported_thing } from "./path/to/file_without_ending";
```

every file is a module, meaning you should avoid namespacing the living daylight out of your classes. The import handles that first namespace layer for you:

```
import { Y as less_general_name } from "my_module";
```

otherwise you will quickly end up with  things like:

```
import * as X from "my_module";
console.log(X.X.Y);
```

Also it makes it difficult for bundlers such as webpack or rollup to analyze your compiled typescript and treeshake (remove unused code through static analyis of dependencies).

Otherwise a namespace with exported members and a class with static members are very similar and will compile to pretty much the same.

Just avoid the depricated module statement, since it conflicts with the meaning of a module as a file that you import.

Here is a link to an example in the TS [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20in%20order%20to%20make%20into%20an%20ES2015%20module%20(same%20mechanics%20in%20typescript)%0D%0A%2F%2F%20there%20should%20be%20a%20root%20level%20export%20(try%20add%20export%20infront%20of%20namespace)%0D%0A%0D%0Anamespace%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20const%20Y%20%3D%201%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Z%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20W%20%3D%202%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

EDIT: Adding explaination from comments on request:

Use namespaces when within a large module you would like to separate blocks of functionality and class when the blocks describe an object or when you jusr want your code more optimizable EDIT ( enter too fast). Generally though namespaces it more often not needed and something we take with us from languages such as c# or java. In your ex i would (if i understand it correctly) make a singleton class in a module (a class with a static get instance function and private constructor or if it is only 1 function, just export it in a module, no objectifiation or namespacing. If you want "namespace" around that function for clairty import like so:

```
import * as MyModule from "somewhere";
MyModule.myexportedFn();
```

Comment: Nice answer, I’m just wondering: there is a reason for namespaces, and there is a reason for classes. All of us wants a modular readable and maintainable code, that’s why we have so much definitions (module, class...). what is the purpose of classes vs namespaces?When is the best practice to use each? I’m sure there is a meaning for each. Also, please reference my real life example: my main.ts manages the application, part of his job is to initiate a single instance of a self contained code that’s doing endless job without exporting an API for main.ts to use. What’s the best practice for that?

Comment: Well. Classes and namespaces are more of a semantical difference since in JS there are only objects and function scopes really.to group code. I would say, use namesoaces when within a module you would like to separate blocks of functionality and class when the blocks describe an object or when you jusr want your code more optimizable

Comment: Edit failed: Use namespaces when within a large module you would like to separate blocks of functionality and class when the blocks describe an object or when you jusr want your code more optimizable EDIT ( enter too fast). Generally though namespaces it more often not needed and something we take with us from languages such as c# or java. In your ex i would (if i understand it correctly) make a singleton class in a module (a class with a static get instance function and private constructor or if it is only 1 function, just export it in a module, no objectifiation or namespacing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details, I agree that the best fit is to just export the single function I need. But I ended up using a namespace so the call to the function will be more readable: instead of doMyWork() I use MyModule.doMyWork(). Please add the important explanations from your comments to your answer so others will find it easily

Comment: I guess "using a namespace" mean you do  an import * as MyModule from "somewhere";

Comment: No my module is like this export namespace MyModule { export function doWork() {} }. and I use it like this: import { MyModule } from ‘filename’. And then: MyModule.doWork()

Comment: I would avoid that if it does not bring any value inside 'filename'. Instead use the import * as MyModule to get a namespace. That way your 'filename' module stays clean.

Comment: what if I want to import and use only some of the functions from another file? Is there a way to add namespacing to those functions?